# Locate a particular string in a directory

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, search, grep, cat

I want to do the following:

`cat *.xml | grep some_string_here`

This tells me if a particular string exists in an xml file in a directory. Unfortunately it does not tell me *which* file.

how can I do this better? `cat` command does not see me to have an switch that adds a filename prefix to the output...

Comment: Migrate to unix se site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cat` is unnecessary (UUOC!)  `grep` will normally tell you which file the matched line was found in when used like this:

```
   grep some_string_here *.xml
```

You can also use the `-H` switch to always to this:

```
   grep -H some_string_here *.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing UUOC to my attention, I feel like a right noob :-)

Comment: LOL, I'd give you an extra +1 if I could for "UUOC".

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
grep some_string_here *.xml
```

instead, then grep will automatically prepend the filename to each match.

Answer (score 2):

Just use grep

`grep some_string *.xml`

The output will be something like

```
a.xml: string containing some_string
xyzzy.xml:some_string in a different line
```

If a file contains more than one occurrence of some_string each occurrence will be printed.
If you use

```
grep -l some_string *.xml
```

only the filename will be printed.

Comment: `-i` is "ignore case" in the versions of `grep` that I know about. Some versions use `-m` to stop after one match.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep some_string_here /dev/null *.xml
```

... is a small improvement over the other suggestions above, since it makes sure that the name of the file containing the match is always printed, even if the current directory only contains one XML file.